Received Import Error while importing an existing function
I have a library installed from google and I was trying to import a function from it yet it says that the function cannot be imported.
The error is as follows:
ImportError: cannot import name 'exp_ratios' from 'Lily.utils.np_utils'

The code is as follows:
from Lily.utils.np_utils import (assert_same_shape,
                                 softmax,
                                 normalize,
                                 exp_ratios,
                                 unnormalize)

but when I checked in np_utils python file I found that the function exp_ratios existed.

your 'information' lacks ... content, helping you is going to be difficult, does this 'library' have documentation, a git repo, documentation ?  ...  python version ... os .... have done any background investigations ....
